# Is there a way in google-analytics to see which browser bounced

Tags: google-analytics

I've detected high bounces in my website. I think it's a technical problem in it's basic. The thing is, I can't find a way in my google-analytics, to see bouncing visits sepratly from the others, and see if there's a certin browser that bounces more then others. Is there any way?
Thanks in advance
Yair

Comment: How have you detected the high bounce rate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858123/how-to-extract-data-from-google-analytics-and-build-a-data-warehouse-webhouse

Comment: It's kinda compicaited, but I have a JS that sometimes runs, and somethimes not, and sets a custom_var for either case. Now, I see the bounce is very high with the JS running, and normal without JS running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using advanced segments (look for it on the dashboard), you can do that. Thanks anyway