# Is there any possibility to extract Google Analytics data and post that to Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-analytics, kibana, raw-data

I have been working on ways to import Google Analytics raw data without having to use a premium account .So far this is the nearest link to what I want to do 
    [How to extract data from Google Analytics and build a data warehouse (webhouse) from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858123/how-to-extract-data-from-google-analytics-and-build-a-data-warehouse-webhouse)
    I want to load that data into elastic search and display using kibana .What is the best ETL approach for this ? Has anyone tried to display GA data using ELK stack ?

Comment: I haven't used elastic search before looks like they have an API but how do you upload data to them?

Comment: This is incredibly broad. Can you split that into multiple questions (i.e. "how do I get GA raw data without a premium account", "how do I import data to elasticsearch" etc. ) ?

Comment: @DaImTo I am really not sure about that .May be exporting GA raw data into hadoop and using a hadoop-elastic connector as described here   http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/11/analytics-with-kibana-and-elasticsearch-through-hadoop-part-1-introduction/

Comment: I think you should contact them.  this question is to broad.   I have never heard of elastic I was just curious I use a custom SSIS task to import my GA data into sql server data warehouse I was just curious really.   If you can figure out how to insert the data the Google analytics API will let you retrieve the data.

Comment: @EikePierstorff when are you going to contact me don't make me go though the company website on your profile please :)

Comment: @DaImTo, done (via the contact form on your website). And elasticsearch is a document based storage engine, together with logstash and kibana (a dashboard software) it's often used for log file analysis (all open source, too). So this might be worth a look (I admin I'm just getting started with elasticsearch).

Comment: Loading csv data exported from google analytics using GA api into elastic search is achievable .What I want to be able to do is importing raw data from GA into a data ware house (probably hadoop or some others if applicable )

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in two times

- First, get the info, a very very useful site is https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/search_analytics but you have first to have a google wembaster tool account and create oauth credential on https://console.developers.google.com/apis
- Then once you have your data, find a way to import them in elasticsearch, I'm still looking for the best way to do so, maybe transform the result table into csv and then using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html

Comment: Despite what their website states, the Java Transport Client is still available. I'm able to connect to my Elasticsearch cloud service with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html

You can use this to poll an endpoint, in this case GA, and load the response data into Elasticsearch. You may want to filter the response with the Split and / or Mutate plugins as well.

Comment: Can you please provide some example for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this same setup.

1. Extracted data from Google Analytics with 7 Dimensions and 6 Metrics, out of which 2 Dimensions were primary key (Timestamp and ID). This was done using R.
2. Did some transformations on the data using linux awk and sed commands.
3. Loaded the data into Apache Hive with the row column formatting, created like total 9 tables.
4. Joined all the 9 tables in Hive using Hive Join queries, with 2 primary keys.
5. Used elasticsearch-hadoop connector to load the final resulting table to elasticsearch. Had to do a little data transformations to match Hive and Elasticsearch data types.
6. Used Kibana to visualize the data in Elasticsearch.

Now I am planning to avoid all the manual steps and somehow automate all the steps above.