# Extracting data from Google Analytics using Python

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have one query in Google APIs. I have attached the pic. Where will you be calling the API from? Is the point where I am struck at Actually I want to use Python language to extract data from Google Analytics So can you tell me which potion to select from the drop down list. Hope my question is clear.[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8Um.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T43qJ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract data from Google Analytics and build a data warehouse (webhouse) from it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858123/how-to-extract-data-from-google-analytics-and-build-a-data-warehouse-webhouse)

Comment: @Blasanka Did you go through the images?